# Правильное употребление слов

Tags: орфоэпия

Можно ли употребить подобное сочетание слов: "Всемирно известная слава"?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Но в очень нетривиальных значениях. 
"Сбораная по хоккею - наша слава. Всемирно известная слава". Здесь "слава" - не отвлеченное существительное, а конкретный объект.
Или в совсем уже "марсианском" варианте, когда надо подчеркнуть именно **известность** славы.
Т.е. сама слава не всемирная, а вот известность о ней - вполне себе глобально-планетарная.
*Всёму миру известно, что пенсионер Имяреков в своей деревне пользуется славой прожженного бабника*. Вот это - всемирно известная слава.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Всемирная слава.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, грубо. Всемирная слава.

Answer (score 0):

Или всемирная известность :-)